# Why is this question “POB?

Tags: support

I asked the following question [Do British people think they are losing face on Brexit?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43268/do-british-people-think-they-are-losing-face-on-brexit?noredirect=1#comment194226_43268) asking to confirm or deny what, according to some articles, appears to be an emerging concern about reputation.

The question was just dismissed as POB....

Comment: My comment on this question was misplaced, after some internet searching I've found "British people" is not an insulting Demonym and I will not be offended if you don't start using "people of britain" or the more specific "the citizens of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, the British Overseas Territories, and the Crown dependencies"

Comment: @daniel - it never crossed my mind that the expression “British people “ could be perceived as an insult by those it refers to.

Answer (score 4):

The question went through some revisions.

The first version was "Are British people losing face on Brexit?" This is a matter of opinion, and probably what earned the first few "Primarily Opinion-Based" closed votes.

The current version is "Do British people think they are losing face on Brexit?" This isn't a notable claim. No-one is saying anything like "85% of UK residents agree or strongly agree with the statement 'We are losing face over Brexit'".

Instead, you found two opinion-writers who say they think they have lost face.

Comment: I see, I missed to post what you call “the notable claim”.